# How to analyze this unusal longitudinal design?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, crossover-study

I have data coming from an unusual design. 10 subjects were drawn to receive an experimental eye drop for reducing intraoccular pressure. One eye was chosen by random and the drops were applied. The intraoccular pressure was measured several times during the following 2 months. Then, after seeing that the effect was gone, the second eye got the drops in each subject. And again, the intraoccular pressure was monitored for another 2 months.

My variables are: Subject ID, Visit (1,2,3, ...), Number of days from treatment, pressure in the treated eye, pressure in the fellow eye, and phase of study (I,II, where II means that this is the second time this subject was treated, when now the treatment eye is the previous fellow eye). How do I analyze this mess ?

Comment: Except for the bit where they wait until "the effect is gone", this seems pretty standard for an ophtamology study, I'd guess there must be other studies with this design that are published. I would assume they would have analyzed this with a mixed effects repeated measures model that account for the correlation between eyes in a subject and the correlation of assessments of the same eye over time. The bit where the duration of observation depends on the effect seems tricky - how is "effect gone" judged and how can we avoid a bias (e.g. due to stopping the time series at the lowest value)?!

Comment: When I said, "effect gone", I meant that once the follow-up period was over, a certain time passed, and then the same subjects went through the treatment again, just with the other eye. I see what you mean regarding bias, although the untreated eye was treated this time. Would you look at the change from baseline or the difference from the fellow eye ? If I use the change from baseline and not the difference from the fellow eye, doesn't that reduce the bias?